Creating a building density layer from point data
I am trying to create a building density layer for large regions. For this reason, I cannot do a count per polygon over a grid (estimation was 70 days for the analysis)
I have point data for buildings and am trying to convert this data to a Boolean raster layer. I have used the rasterize tool, but cannot figure out how to assign true or false (I only get the building points to = 0).
I assume that from here, I can use raster calculator to multiply this Boolean layer with a larger resolution to get a density layer. At this point, how would I quantify the number of building pixels per larger pixel?
Another option I have been looking at is kernel density. However I do not want to over smooth as I want to be able to delineate urban vs. rural.

Kernel Density is the right function for a heat map. Smoothing is a function of parameters -- You could always run two density calculations, then mask them together.
